# I'm having an issue implementing an API into a bukkit plugin

Tags: java, api, minecraft, bukkit, integrate

I'm trying to set up this API so that I can update player scoreboards and things when they buy items.

The plugin I'm using is called SignShop and can be found here:

http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/signshop/pages/sign-shop-api/

That's not my issue though, the issue is that none of the events are firing from the looks of it.

Here is my class where I was trying some debugging.

```
package me.galaxywarrior6.minecraftgta.events;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.wargamer2010.signshop.events.SSMoneyTransactionEvent;
import org.wargamer2010.signshop.events.SSPostTransactionEvent;
import org.wargamer2010.signshop.events.SSPreTransactionEvent;
import org.wargamer2010.signshop.events.SSTouchShopEvent;

public class SignBuyEvent implements Listener{

    public void onSignBuy(SSMoneyTransactionEvent event){
        Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("one!");
    }
    public void onSignBuy(SSPreTransactionEvent event){
        Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("two!");
    }
    public void onSignBuy(SSPostTransactionEvent event){
        Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("three!");
    }
    public void onSignBuy(SSTouchShopEvent event){
        Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("four!");
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me in implementing this API, I haven't done anything besides set up the events because that's all it really tells you to do.

Comment: I wanted to specify that it shows NOTHING up in console. It's as if they're not being used at all.

Comment: Where are you registering your listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you need `@EventHandler` right above all of your events:

```
@EventHandler //this must be before ALL events
public void onSignBuy(SSMoneyTransactionEvent event){
    Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("one!");
}
```

also, you may not be registering events. In your main file (the one that `extends JavaPlugin`), make sure you have this in your `onEnable()`:

```
this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new SignBuyEvent(), this);
```

So, your `SignBuyEvent` class should look like this:

```
public class SignBuyEvent implements Listener{
  @EventHandler
  public void onSignBuy(SSMoneyTransactionEvent event){
    Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("one!");
  }

  @EventHandler
  public void onSignBuy(SSPreTransactionEvent event){
    Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("two!");
  }

  @EventHandler
  public void onSignBuy(SSPostTransactionEvent event){
    Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("three!");
  }

  @EventHandler
  public void onSignBuy(SSTouchShopEvent event){
    Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("four!");
  }
}
```

and your `onEnable()` method in your `Main` class should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onEnable(){
  this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new SignBuyEvent(), this);

  //other things that you have in your onEnable here
}
```

Comment: You know what, I feel really stupid lol. It was like 5am when I was doing all of this. Thank you for solving this little oversight of mine. This did solve my issue.